# pre_get_posts with get_posts

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, pre-get-posts

So in the template I've multiple featured posts and sliders and 2 default loops.

I use `get_posts` for everything except default loops (obviously).

Now the issue I'm having is excluding `get_posts` posts from main loops. I could have gone `query_posts` way but impact on performance is bad and I want to work on main loop even before its generated.

So I'm going to use `pre_get_posts` in functions.php.

Inside pre_get_posts I'm going to modify main loop and exclude get_posts data.

I've following problems:

1. I need to use get_posts inside template, so I need to declare variable holding those as global :( otherwise it will not be accessible inside my template.
2. get_posts inside pre_get_posts gives me memory issues: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes

```
function RoomsGazette_homepage_content( $query ) {

    //$tweets         = getTweets( 4, $titan->getOption( 'tweets_from_user' ) );

    $header_sliders = get_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'roomsgazette_hp_position', 'meta_value' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 5, ) );

    //$footer_sliders = get_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'roomsgazette_hp_position', 'meta_value' => 2, 'posts_per_page' => 5, ) );

    //$featured       = get_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'roomsgazette_hp_position', 'meta_value' => 3, 'posts_per_page' => 2, ) );

    $exclude_ids    = array();

    foreach ( $header_sliders as $tmp ) {
        array_push( $exclude_ids, $tmp->ID );
    }

    foreach ( $footer_sliders as $tmp ) {
        array_push( $exclude_ids, $tmp->ID );
    }

    foreach ( $featured as $tmp ) {
        array_push( $exclude_ids, $tmp->ID );
    }

    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude_ids );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'RoomsGazette_homepage_content' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you are invoking an infinite loop, which causes the memory exhaustion. To avoid it, put the following at the beginning of your function:

```
// avoid infinite loop
remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', __FUNCTION__ );
```

It makes sure the you are not hooking it into `pre_get_posts` over and over again, re-initiating your `get_posts()` call over and over again.

Secondly, make use of `WP_Query`'s - and subsequently `get_posts`'s - the [`fields` parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter), choosing `ids` as value, which reduces the memory-/workload by getting only IDs.

Comment: Thanks! Second part: WP_Query instead of get_posts? I'm using not only IDS, I also need $featured inside theme file, so I can display them. Or do you think its better to have two get_posts one in pre_get_posts with only IDS and one in template? Seems redundant

Comment: Is there a way to get $header_sliders inside template without declaring it as global?

Comment: You can use `'fields' => 'ids'` with `get_posts()`, which is only a wrapper for `WP_Query`. Using a `global` is probably the simplest way, otherwise you could use transients, especially if the values stay the same a lot, or you construct a class, whose instance contains/stores the data. The last two options need some more work though. @SandroDzneladze